# switch between two images onclick javascript

Tags: javascript, image, onclick

This question has been asked before, but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

I have multiple images in a row which are used as navigation and are absolutely positioned on the side of my page. When one is clicked, I want the image to change from a white dot to an orange dot, and the dot that HAD been orange to become white.

I have tried many different ways, but this is what I have at the moment.

full code here: [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/BK68X/1/)

```
function switchImage(){
    if (document.getElementById("img1").src == "http://scoutingwithtroop225.com/White%20Dot.jpeg"){
        document.getElementById("img1").src = "http://dbprng00ikc2j.cloudfront.net/work/image/269918/qg7swq/ORANGE_DOT.jpg";
    }else{
            (document.getElementById("img1").src = "http://scoutingwithtroop225.com/White%20Dot.jpeg");
    }
}
```

Comment: ReferenceError: switchImage is not defined

Comment: Did you look at the console? When a picture is clicked, the function switchImage is unknown. Change the jsfiddle settings to one of the two no-wraps and it'll find the function: http://jsfiddle.net/WC7yg/

Comment: in the fiddle, change the js option from onLoad to no wrap in - head, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function switchImg(){
    if($('#white').css('display') == 'none'){
        $('#white').css('display', 'block');
        $('#orange').css('display', 'none');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#white').css('display', 'none');
        $('#orange').css('display', 'block');
    }
  }
</script>


<div class="dots">
    <img id="white" onclick="switchImg()" src="http://scoutingwithtroop225.com/White%20Dot.jpeg" />
    <img id="orange" style="display:none" onclick="switchImg()" src="http://dbprng00ikc2j.cloudfront.net/work/image/269918/qg7swq/ORANGE_DOT.jpg" />
</div>
```

[PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/S6tCy6PHU3IiQbI4UIOP?p=preview)

Comment: There is no `JQuery` tag for the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have used two images for u and here is the working example
```

Untitled Document

```
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dots">
        <a href="#top"><img id="img1" class="individualDot" src="http://scoutingwithtroop225.com/White%20Dot.jpeg" height="170"></a>
        <a href="#listen"><img id="img2" class="individualDot"  src="http://dbprng00ikc2j.cloudfront.net/work/image/269918/qg7swq/ORANGE_DOT.jpg" 
        height="170"></a>


    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#img1").click(function(){
        var img1 = $('#img1').attr("src");
        var img2 = $('#img2').attr("src");

        $("#img2").attr("src",img1);
        $("#img1").attr("src",img2);
        })

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no `JQuery` tag for the question.